# How to add whitespace infront of <li>

Tags: html, css

How can i add whitespace in front of `<li>` i would prefer not using `<pre>` since the paragraph inside my  `<li>` are quite long it would take time adding breakline manually also `<pre>` ruin my site css margin design

```html
<ol>
  <li>                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet maecenas quis risus non sem hendrerit mollis in et enim consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
  <li>                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet maecenas quis risus non sem hendrerit mollis in et enim consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
  <li>                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet maecenas quis risus non sem hendrerit mollis in et enim consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
</ol>
```

**Expected Result:**

```
1.                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet maecenas quis risus non sem hendrerit mollis in et enim consectetur adipiscing elit.
2.                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet maecenas quis risus non sem hendrerit mollis in et enim consectetur adipiscing elit.
3.                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet maecenas quis risus non sem hendrerit mollis in et enim consectetur adipiscing elit.
```

Comment: Is this purely visual spacing or do you require space characters to be in there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a `padding-left` to the `<li>`

```css
li {
  padding-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet maecenas quis risus non sem hendrerit mollis in et enim consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
  <li> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet maecenas quis risus non sem hendrerit mollis in et enim consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
  <li> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet maecenas quis risus non sem hendrerit mollis in et enim consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: okay that work also enclosing `<li>` with `<p>` would make it respect `margin-right: 5%;
margin-left:5%;` thanks

Comment: @PresnerPontillas you are getting spacing in the next line too. is it okay for you?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with the CSS property `text-indent`.

```css
li{
    text-indent: 4em;
}
```

```html
 <ol>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet maecenas quis risus non sem hendrerit mollis in et enim consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet maecenas quis risus non sem hendrerit mollis in et enim consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet maecenas quis risus non sem hendrerit mollis in et enim consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score -1):

To insert blank spaces in text in HTML,type   for each space to add.

```
<ol>
  <li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet maecenas quis risus non sem hendrerit mollis in et enim consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
  <li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet maecenas quis risus non sem hendrerit mollis in et enim consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
  <li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet maecenas quis risus non sem hendrerit mollis in et enim consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
</ol>
```

[Fiddle:](https://jsfiddle.net/nikshep/xmzkafob/1/)

Comment: this would ruin my css margin design

Comment: You should add css as well to the question in that case.

Comment: @niku the question is (and always was) labled with CSS.